# Clone Linux/Win7 dual-boot to smaller hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, multi-boot, clone

I have a Linux Mint / Windows 7 dual boot setup that is on a big hard drive that I'd like to use for something else. I have a smaller hard drive that will fit everything with room to spare.

Currently the smaller hard drive is connected via external usb to the laptop.

Is there a way to clone the entire drive, partitions and all, to the smaller drive so I can just swap them and get back up and running with no fuss (ie. GRUB)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-Clone linux partitions first with clonezilla, if still bigger then your hard drive check the option "-icds" :

[image]

2-resize it with gparted to make space to win 7.

4-clone win 7 partition.

3-if you get boot problems do update to grub :
[How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

ps:
sorry i can't write better than this :/ .

Comment: Thanks for the info. I haven't had the time to let it complete yet but it looked like it was working. (350GB over USB 2.0 takes a long while)

Comment: @leetwanker Why would you accept but not upvote?